# Sympy outputs a derivative with log(e)

Tags: python, sympy

I'm using Sympy to calculate derivatives and some other things. I tried to calculate the derivative of `"e**x + x + 1"`, and it returns `e**x*log(e) + 1` as the result, but as far as I know the correct result should be `e**x + 1`. What's going on here?

Full code:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

x = symbols("x")
_fOfX = "e**x + x + 1"
sympyFunction = parse_expr(_fOfX)
dSeconda = diff(sympyFunction,x,1)
print(dSeconda)
```

Comment: Aren't the answers the same if `log` is natural logarithm?

Comment: `log(e)` == 1, so the answer is correct, if not written as simply as it could

Comment: btw, can't you use `exp(x)` instead of `e**x`?

Comment: I forgot that log(x), without a second argument computes the base e log of x, so its correct.

Answer (score 2):

The answer correctly includes log(e) because you never specified what "e" is. It's just a letter like "a" or "b".

The Euler number 2.71828... is represented as E in SymPy. But usually, writing `exp(x)` is preferable because the notation is unambiguous, and also because SymPy is going to return `exp(x)` anyway. Examples:

```
>>> fx = E**x + x + 1
>>> diff(fx, x, 1)
exp(x) + 1
```

or with exp notation:

```
>>> fx = exp(x) + x + 1
>>> diff(fx, x, 1)
exp(x) + 1
```

Avoid creating expressions by parsing strings, unless you really need to and know why you need it.

Comment: Actually I didnt know that E means the e constant in sympy, indeed I never defined it since that on the sympy docs they tell you to import mpath and use its definitions of the e constant.

Comment: Just type sympy math constantson google:  http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6/modules/mpmath/functions/constants.html

Comment: It's not very prominently stated, but you can find constant names for current SymPy [here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#exp1). The Google search does not lead to this page, unfortunately.